# GCP Kubernetes nodes location

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, azure-application-insights, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a micro service scaled out across several pods in a Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine. Being in a multi-cloud-shop, we have our logging/monitoring/telemetry in Azure Application Insights.
Our data should be kept inside Europe, so our GCP Kubernetes cluster is set up with

```
Master zone: europe-west1-b
Node zones: europe-west1-b
```

When I create a node pool on this cluster, the nodes apparently has the zone europe-west1-b (as expected), seen from the Google Cloud Platform Console "Node details".

However, in Azure Application Insights, from the telemetry reported from the applications running in pods in this node pool, the client_City is reported as "Mountain View" and client_StateOrProvince is "California", and some cases "Ann Arbor" in "Michigan".

At first I waived this strange location as just some inter-cloud-issue (e.g. defaulting to something strange when not filling out the information as expected on the receiving end, or similar).

But now, Application Insights actually pointed out that there is a quite significant performance difference depending on if my pod is running in Michigan or in California, which lead me to belive that these fields are actually correct.

Is GCP fooling me? Am I looking at the wrong place? How can I make sure my GCP Kubernetes nodes are running in Europe?

This is essential for me to know, both from a GCPR perspective, and of course performance (latency) wise.

Comment: Related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/766720/why-is-my-vm-created-in-gce-asia-east1-is-getting-a-us-ip-address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Azure Application Insights are fooling you, because the external IP was registered by Google in California, not considering that these are used by data-centers distributed all over the globe. also have a GCE instance deployed to Frankfurt am Main, while the IP appears as if it would be Mountain View. [StackDriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/) might report the actual locations (and not some vague GeoIP locations).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That would make sense I guess. However the part with some nodes getting IP-addresses then registered at "Ann Arbor" in Michigan having better latency is still a bit odd, but I guess I have to live with that.